# set background of UIscrollview.

Tags: ios, uiview, background, uiscrollview

I have 2 questions:

1. I have quite a few controls that I ended up laying them as below. How do I set background image for the area under scroll?

[image]

I added code like this but it does not show under scroll area:

```
[self.view addSubview:_scrollView];

UIImageView *tempImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Cust_info_background.png"]];

[self.view addSubview: tempImageView];
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:tempImageView];
[self.scrollView addSubview:tempImageView];
[self.scrollView sendSubviewToBack:tempImageView];
```

[image]

2. I have a UIPickerView control in same view (City Picker). When all these controls were directly under top level view (view above Scroll View), I used to get numberOfComponentsInPickerView() and numberOfRowsInComponent() callbacks. Now I don't get them anymore. This is how my class is defined.

   @interface ewfCustInfoViewController : UIViewController 
    < UITextFieldDelegate, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource >

What could be going on?

Thank you

Comment: Who do you want with `UIImageView` ?

Comment: @anhtu i didn't get you.

Comment: Do you want the `UIImageView` cover full background of `UIScrollView`? I don't know `the area under scroll` mean.

Comment: @anhtu yes. i want same background for both top level uiview and the view under scroll. the background of labels and uitextfield should be same as whatever image is displayed as background to the area on its right (which is main UIView).

     [self.view addSubview: tempImageView];
     [self.view sendSubviewToBack:tempImageView];

Comment: Why did you add background `[self.view addSubview:_scrollView];` and `[self.scrollView addSubview:tempImageView];`? Why not just  `[self.view addSubview:_scrollView];` and set `self.scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]`?

Comment: i don't want clear color. i want that same image (background) you see on right (when it is rotated) to be behind the controls as well.

Comment: I tried self.scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor] but it still shows white background and not the image that is filled between this view and screen view.

Comment: Because in your scrollview, you added a view. Set its background become clear also.

Comment: didn't help. wish there is some good video tutorial on understanding these views.